# Interface Vs Abstract classes C++

Tags: c++, interface, abstract-class

Can an interface in C++ have non virtual functions ?

or

An interface in C++ can contain only non virtual function (proto types)?

Comment: What does "interface" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally an "interface" class (in just about all OO languages) is a class with just an interface, no data and no implementation.

In C++ such a class is a class with only pure abstract functions, so no you can't have an "interface" class in C++ if you have non-virtual functions.

Comment: Thanks Joachim I understand your way  of answering

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not have interfaces per se. Thus no restrictions are imposed on them.

Abstract classes are usually used to represent interfaces. It is a matter of convention whether you define default implementations for virtual methods and allow final methods in interface-like classes.

Comment: Since C++11, there's a contextual keyword `final` that implies `virtual`, so your last sentence is a bit vague if you intended to refer to non-virtual functions as well as final, virtual ones.

Comment: By 'final' I meant old-fashioned, vintage finals, those that do not have 'virtual' keyword attached.

'Non-virtual' would be more correct term, probably.

Comment: Well, ironically, "non-virtual finals" can be hidden by derived functions, whereas actual finals can *not* be hidden, thus being actually even more final :-)

Comment: Just because an override in a child-class drops the word `virtual` from the declaration doesn't mean the function stops being virtual. Once a member function has been declared `virtual` it will stay virtual no matter how far down the inheritance-chain you go, with or without any further use of the `virtual` keyword. So before C++11 and the `final` special symbol (it's not a keyword) there was no way of making a "final" function.